# Converting string to time in python is giving error

Tags: python, python-datetime

this question might be answered but I can't find link. I'm trying to convert string to time.
My string looks like '9 a.m.'

`x = datetime.datetime.strptime(start,"%I:%M %p")`

---

I get following error :

`time data '4:30 p.m.' does not match format '%I:%M %p'`

Where I'm wrong ??

Comment: "p.m." isn't the same as "pm". The dots should not be there.

Comment: Why don't you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=replace#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) of `%I`, `%M` and `%p` to try understand the error?

Comment: Do you mean that I should change %p to something else ? If yes, then what should I use  instead of %p ?

Comment: a.m. and p.m. are not supported, look at the documentation. You'll have to code something yourself to first remove the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that "p.m." is not the same as "pm", and `%p` is looking only for "am" or "pm".

In order to convert your string `start` from "4 p.m." to "4 pm", you can use

`start = start.replace(".", "")`

This replaces all "." characters in the string with nothing at all.

If you remove "." from your string before you convert it to a datetime, it should cause no problems.